# Pandas data frame to dictionary of lists

Tags: python, pandas, highcharts

How to use Python or Pandas (preferably) to convert a Pandas DataFrame to dictionary of lists for input into highcharts?

The closest I got was:

```
df.T.to_json('bar.json', orient='index')
```

But this is a *dict of dicts* instead of *dict of lists*.

My input:

```
import pandas
import numpy as np
 
df = pandas.DataFrame({
    "date": ['2014-10-1', '2014-10-2', '2014-10-3', '2014-10-4', '2014-10-5'],
    "time": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    "temp": np.random.random_integers(0, 10, 5),
    "foo": np.random.random_integers(0, 10, 5)
})

df2 = df.set_index(['date'])
df2
```

Output:

```
           time  temp  foo
date                      
2014-10-1     1     3    0
2014-10-2     2     8    7
2014-10-3     3     4    9
2014-10-4     4     4    8
2014-10-5     5     6    2
```

Desired Output: I am using this output in Highcharts, which requires it to be a *dictionary of lists* like so:

```
{'date': ['2014-10-1', '2014-10-2', '2014-10-3', '2014-10-4', '2014-10-5'],
 'foo': [7, 2, 5, 5, 6],
 'temp': [8, 6, 10, 10, 3],
 'time': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
In [199]: df2.reset_index().to_dict(orient='list')
Out[199]: 
{'date': ['2014-10-1', '2014-10-2', '2014-10-3', '2014-10-4', '2014-10-5'],
 'foo': [8, 1, 8, 8, 1],
 'temp': [10, 10, 8, 3, 10],
 'time': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
```

Comment: I'm a little surprised there's no `to_json` orient for this!

Answer (score 1):

to create a list of the dictionaries per line

```
post_data_list = []
for i in df2.index:
  data_dict = {}
  for column in df2.columns:
    data_dict[column] = df2[column][i]
  post_data_list.append(data_dict)
```