# Pandas dataframe to dictionary of lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

Having a dataframe of the form :

```
element1   | element2  |  element3
cat           bird          plane
dog           poodle        cloud
pig           bike          sky
```

I want to convert it to a dictionary of lists of the form

```
{ 'element1' : ['cat', 'dog', 'pig'], 
  'element2' : ['bird', 'poodle', 'bike'],
  'element3' : ['plane', 'cloud', 'sky']  }
```

I am looking at the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) of the `.to_dict` method, but none of the options seem to do what I need.

Comment: Duplicate: [Pandas data frame to dictionary of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26964993/pandas-data-frame-to-dictionary-of-lists)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) with `list` parameter:

```
d = df.to_dict('list')
print (d)
{'element1': ['cat', 'dog', 'pig'],
 'element2': ['bird', 'poodle', 'bike'], 
 'element3': ['plane', 'cloud', 'sky']}
```

Answer (score 2):

Usual to_dict bases on index elements as key values, so transpose your dataframe and apply list by row followed by dictionary conversion

```
df.T.apply(list,1).to_dict()
```

Out:

```
{'element1': ['cat', 'dog', 'pig'],
 'element2': ['bird', 'poodle', 'bike'],
 'element3': ['plane', 'cloud', 'sky']}
```